# Terraform / atlantis creates locks for no apparent reason

Tags: terraform, atlantis

I have set up [atlantis](https://www.runatlantis.io/) and configured multiple `projects`.

I am not using `workspaces` (therefore, for each project only the `default` workspace should be applicable).

However, when creating a GitHub Pull Request that includes changes to multiple projects, I get the following error(s)

> dir: terragrunt/path1/to/something workspace: default

```
The default workspace is currently locked by another command that is running for this pull request.
Wait until the previous command is complete and try again.
dir: terragrunt/path1/to/anotherthing workspace: default
```

> dir: terragrunt/path2/to/anotherthing workspace: default

```
The default workspace is currently locked by another command that is running for this pull request.
Wait until the previous command is complete and try again.
```

This is despite the fact that docs [state](https://www.runatlantis.io/docs/locking.html):

> Only the directory in the repo and Terraform workspace are locked, not the whole repo.

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

I saw something similar after setting

```yaml
parallel_plan: true
parallel_apply: true
```

in my `atlantis.yaml`.

Removing these fixed the issue for me, and I assume setting them to `false` would achieve the same thing.

I am not 100% clear **WHY** this is happening yet, but it appears to have something to do with the way Atlantis locks and terraform workspaces interact, as the default workspace is called `default` and it appears that Atlantis locks, might be related to the workspace name.

It looks like you have already reported the issue [here](https://github.com/runatlantis/atlantis/issues/2200) and that the maintainers responded that there is a [merged but currently (2022-04-29) unreleased fix](https://github.com/runatlantis/atlantis/pull/2131).

Hope this helps others who happen to stumble upon this...